# Jquery making Rateit (star) plugin work for added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have some rating code:

```
$('div.rateit').rateit();
```

I want it also to function for added elements.

Here is the plugin: http://rateit.codeplex.com/

Comment: How are you adding the elements (native JavaScript, jQuery, some server-side code, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you might need to use [jQuery on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like this:

```
  $('div.rateit').on('event which triggers the rateit()', rateit);
```

Comment: which event should I use. I would the rateit(); to be called right after they are added.

Comment: What exactly `rateit()` does? If it only applies a style, I'd suggest using pete answer: add some class to them (with `.attr('class', 'rateit')`, for example), and set some style rules for it before.

Comment: It applies rating. Both styling and some other js functionality

Answer (score 3):

It works! :

If you have a look at the source of the rateit plugin (src/jquery.rateit.js) you'll see that at the end of file appears the invocation:

```
//invoke it on all .rateit elements. This could be removed if not wanted.
$(function () { $('div.rateit, span.rateit').rateit(); });
```

What you need to do is to invoke this function again once you load or add elements.

In my case I was using jQuery.ajax (...) and when loading new elements with the 'rateit' css class it wasn't working. Now they do with this line inside the ajax response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('div.rateit, span.rateit').rateit(); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding the new elements server-side, just add the CSS class `rateit` to each element you are adding. Assuming you only want to make the `div` elements a `rateit` object, your existing jQuery code will work.