# Rateit plugin not working for content appended after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using rateit plugin by http://gjunge.github.io/rateit.js/examples/

Every thing works fine until i load content with starts on page dynamically after page load. Stars simply don't appear.

My dynamically generated content which is appended to the page looks likes this(form ajax request):

```html
<div class="caption">
    <p id="productNameInFeeds"><a href="https://youlense.com/view/IPHONE">
            <b>IPHONE</b></a> - I PHONE 6S</p>
    <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="3.00"
         data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true" data-rateit-max="10">
    </div>
    <div>
        3.00 Stars | 2 Reviews | 10 Views | 1 Followers
    </div>
</div>
```

my js file looks likes this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var page = 1;

$("#load_more_feeds").click(function(){
    $.post("my/feeds/more",
            {
                page: page
            },
            function(data, status){

                if(data != ''){
                    $("#feedHolder").append(data);
                    page = page + 1;
                }

            });
$('div.rateit, span.rateit').rateit();
});

});
```

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33071447/3499595

Just after you append the new content, call this:

```
$('div.rateit, span.rateit').rateit();
```

This initializes all the `rateit` elements.

Comment: thanks for answer, i have pasted javascript as well with you code, still doesnt work :(

Comment: thankx.. it works just had to move the code you provided one bracket up... (y)

Comment: Excellent! This saved me some hair pulling.